# How to use Google Maps with Marko.js and Lasso.js and link global variables to other templates

Tags: javascript, node.js, marko, lasso.js

I'm in a project using Marko.js with Lasso.js for building .js and .scss code. I can successfully interact with Google Maps API through `<script>` tags. I wish to send latitude and longitude values to other templates, how do I do this?

I tried using [this](https://markojs.com/docs/rendering/#global-data) guide inside the docs but it didn't work. I tried to reference a global variable from an `index.marko` with inline js inside a `<script>` tag.

The reason I'm forced to use inline js has to do with Lasso.js and Google Maps using `<script async defer src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/...&callback=initMap'/>`, it has a callback to an inline js function called initMap() inside another `<script>` tag. Every time I tried to move the inline js code to an individual .js file, by adding it to the `browser.json` file like everything else. It throws an error saying that there is no initMap function loaded.

Ok so here is my root directory

```
src
|_ pages
   |_ home
      |_ index.marko
      |_ index.js
src
|_ components
   |_ location-search
      |_ index.marko
```

This is location-search/index.marko:

```
div.search-container.location-search
  div.input-field
    p.input-label -- Search
    input.controls#pac-input type="text" placeholder="Search Box"
  div#map

<script>
  functioninitMap() {
    // Do Google Maps stuff and obtain an array of lat lng values.
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/...&callback=initMap"/>
```

This is home/index.marko

```
lasso-page package-path="./browser.json"
<!DOCTYPE html>
html lang="en"
  head
    meta charset="UTF-8"
    meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"
    meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"
    title -- App
    lasso-head
  body
    location-search
  browser-refresh
  lasso-body
```

I expect to be able to access from another page the array of latitude and longitude values obtained in `components/location-search/index.marko.` Marko is a great tool, it just needs more documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I'm forced to use inline js has to do with Lasso.js and Google Maps using https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/...&callback=initMap'/>, it has a callback to an inline js function called initMap() inside another  tag.

I'd recommend using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/load-google-maps-api.  It allows you to load the google maps api and get access to it without creating a global handler.

```
import loadGoogleMapsApi from "load-google-maps-api";

class {
  onMount() {
    loadGoogleMapsApi.then((googleMaps) => {
      this.map = new googleMaps.Map(this.getEl('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: 40.7484405,
          lng: -73.9944191
        },
        zoom: 12
      });
    });
  }
}

div.search-container.location-search
  div.input-field
    p.input-label -- Search
    input.controls#pac-input type="text" placeholder="Search Box"
  div key="map"
```

> I tried using this guide inside the docs but it didn't work. I tried to reference a global variable from an index.marko with inline js inside a  tag.

As far as this goes, the globals talked about in this doc aren't globals like `window` is a global.  They're more like "render globals" only available in the templates, but available to all of them while rendering.

Comment: This is just great!! Thank you very much for your help. I have another problem you might be familiarized with. I'm using the `broswer-refresh` npm library. It works perfectly when running the `browser-refresh server.js` console command. But, when running `node server.js` the map stops working. I tried to log just after calling onMount() method and it didn't show the message in the console.

Comment: Edit: The error I get with `node server.js` is: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': Nodes of type '#text' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'.`